# Revision Updater

Tags: c#

I want to make a method that will check the server's revision, check the "website" for a revision higher than it, then change the server's revision.

Here's what I've gotten so far.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Update the Emulator's Revision!
    /// </summary>
    private static void Update()
    {
        int pause = 900;
        Console.WriteLine("Checking your revision");
        Thread.Sleep(pause);
        Console.WriteLine("------->" + Revision);
        Console.WriteLine("Checking Checking the newest revision online");
        Thread.Sleep(pause);
        //string Test = "Anything" > Revision;
        string Website = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://whatever.com/revision.php/");
        //if (Website.Contains(Test))
        //{
        //}
    }
```

Is there a way to find anything that is over "Revision" on "website"?

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: I'm just starting, I don't know any other way to stop the Thread for a few seconds, then start it again.

Comment: I mean what is the specific question? - You explained what you want to do, but did not present a related question.

Comment: It's at the bottom, Now edited sorry.

Comment: Okay then, why do you want to pause the thread? In your code, it's just pausing for 9/10 second and then continuing. Is it that you want the output to pause so the user can read what's happening before you go on?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you simply want to check a "revision string" if it is higher than what you got locally.

As I see it, it depends on what you use as a revision. 
If it looks something like "1.0.0.1" (major, minor, built and so on) I would break the string apart with the Split method and convert it into integers, then compare each part separately.

I'm not aware that a simple "revision-compare"-method exists.